# Could not autowire bean in test class

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, autowired, intellij-14

I have a project with Spring MVC and Spring Boot and I use IntelliJ.
My Project is like this :

```
main -> java -> mypackage -> authentification -> WebSecurityConfig.java
                          -> configuration -> ApplicationConfiguration.java
                          -> controller -> WelcomeMessageController.java
                          -> service -> WelcomeMessageService.java
                                     -> Impl -> WelcomeMessageServiceImpl.java
test -> java -> mypackage -> WelcomeMessageTest.java
```

I annotate the service implementation with `@Service`.

I annotate the configuration file with

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "mypackage")
```

In the controller, I inject the service with

```
@Autowired
WelcomeMessageService welcomeMessageService;
```

In the test class, I inject the same service with the same annotation:

```
@Autowired
WelcomeMessageService welcomeMessageService;
```

I annotate the test class with :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationConfiguration.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
```

In the controller, the injection works fine but in the test class, IntelliJ says:

> Could not autowire. No beans of type WelcomeService found.

When I run the test it works, but I don't understand why IntelliJ says that it can't find the bean.

I found this topics that says that it happens some time with IntelliJ but I don't want to use the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation.

Does anyone have another solution to solve this problem ?

Comment: `WelcomeMessageManager` is `WelcomeMessageService`?

Comment: Yes, this is the service. I copy/paste the wrong name.

Comment: Can you provide the full code for WelcomeMessageService, it's impl and the test class?

Answer (score 3):

For me it was a **component scan** issue my models are in a **separate module** then my Spring Boot App. Normally, **@SpringBootApplication** has a **@ComponentScan** which when not specified will scan as follows:

> - Either {@link #basePackageClasses} or {@link #basePackages} (or
>     its alias  * {@link #value}) may be specified to define specific
>     packages to scan. If specific  * packages are not defined, scanning
>     will occur from the package of the  * class that declares this
>     annotation.

If your SpringBootApp Main class is on a different package then you want to specify the ComponentScan. Same thing if you are using multiple modules, specify it on your Configuration class.

Config class Annotations:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "app.data")
```

Testclass Annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.class, DynamoConfig.class })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of not being able to AutowWire beans into the Integration test classes. Your question helped me in solving that with the addition of "ContextConfiguration" annocation instead of "SpringApplicationConfiguration" which I was using.

However the only difference I can see now is that you are missing the @EnableAutoConfiguration in the Application class (which extendends SpringBootServletInitializer) or the class where you have your @Configuration.

Hopefully that should resolve your issue. Bottom line is this is caused to inappropriate annotations at in this very specific case.